# NSFetchedResultsController in a loop to check attribute value

Tags: ios, core-data

I have this piece of code inside my `viewDidLoad` method to check the name of the section from the `UITableView`. What I need is a way to make a similar loop inside the same method to be able to know an attribute value from all stored objects. The Core Data entity is defined in a `NSManagedObject` subclass called ToDoItem.

```
  for(int i = 0; i < [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count]; i++)
  {
      id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> theSection = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections]objectAtIndex:i];
      NSString *sectionName = [theSection name];
      if ([sectionName isEqualToString:@"0"])
      { 
          haySeccion0 = @"si";
      }
  }
```

Comment: What property define a `ToDoItem` in a specific section (section '0' in your case)? what property do you need updated with what value?

Comment: I don't need to update any value, what I need is to check the value of an attribute from every object, and depending on this value call an action. The piece of code in my question is what am I doing to check the sections not the objects inside the section.

Comment: Then what is the property type and name (for the one you like to check)?

Comment: @DanShelly, the property's name is borrar and it is a string property. Pseudo-code: if (borrar isEqualToString @"si se puede borrar"){ has0Section = @"si";}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion for you is:

fetch only what you need:

```
NSManagedObjectContext* context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init] //or use your current context;
context.persistentStoreCoordinator = //Get the coordinator

NSExpressionDescription* objectIdDesc = [NSExpressionDescription new];
objectIdDesc.name = @"objectID";
objectIdDesc.expression = [NSExpression expressionForEvaluatedObject];
objectIdDesc.expressionResultType = NSObjectIDAttributeType;

NSFetchRequest* r = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"EntityName"];
[r setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[r setPropertiesToFetch:@[objectIdDesc,@"borrar"]];
[r setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"has0Section = %@",@"si"]];
NSError* error = nil;
NSArray* results = [context executeFetchRequest:r error:&error];
//Error handling ...
```

results will now contain all objects (as dictionaries) on section 0 and their `borrar` property, perform whatever logic you like on that.

You can perform this code in the background and set the `map` to some private variable of your view controller (synchronise on some lock when needed).

Comment: thank you for time and effort. I will try your proposal.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to check all the objects then perform an action on a section based on  an attribute being on an object.

Why not enumerate all objects, then use indexPathForObject to retrieve the section.

It isn't clear why you need to do this section by section..

Comment: I will try doing what you say, I will enumerate all objects...thank you